# Best way to manage 100+ image targets in Vuforia/Unity

Tags: unity, vuforia

My current project is an app that will handle about 122 Vuforia image targets. My first approahc was to create an ImageTarget prefab and instantiate it with the right texture and TargetName, yet I found that Vuforia package for Unity doesnt allow to assign a value to those fields from code, only through editor.
I really cant believe that there is no other way than manually adding 122 ImageTargets objects to the scene, but cant find anything related. So, what I need is some way to handle this witha list of tagged images, and call an event function with the corresponding tag to display the info belonging to that tag. Is there a way to do it?